# Stop replacing text in string after first replacement in PHP

Tags: php, string

Here is an example:

```
$original_string = 'I like apples very much. I want an apple.';

$temp_string = str_replace('apples', '_apples_', $original_string);
// $temp_string is now: I like _apples_ very much. I want an apple.

$final_string = str_replace('apple', '_apple_', $temp_string);
// $final_string is now: I like __apple_s_ very much. I want an _apple_.
```

This is not what I intend to do. I want the final string to be:

```
I like _apples_ very much. I want an _apple_.
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
$original_string = 'I like apples very much. I want an apple.';
$final_string = str_replace(['apples', 'apple'], ['_apples_', '_apple_'], $original_string);

echo $original_string;
// I like __apple_s_ very much. I want an _apple_.
```

Reversing the replacement order does not help either:

```
$original_string = 'I like apples very much. I want an apple.';
$original_string = str_replace(['apple', 'apples'], ['_apple_', '_apples_'], $original_string);

echo $original_string;
// I like _apple_s very much. I want an _apple_.
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` it use Regular Expression instead of string for the replacement

```
$original_string = 'I like apples very much. I want an apple.';
$final_string = preg_replace("/(apples?)/", "_$1_", $original_string);

echo $final_string;
```

Regex explanation : https://regex101.com/r/EzxqWR/2 and demo : https://3v4l.org/uTDIs

```
                  (1)         (2)
               vvvvvvvv      vvvv
preg_replace("/(apples?)/", "_$1_", $original_string);
```

1. It will search string `apple` or `apples`
2. and will put the result to `$1` and became `_apple_` or `_apples_`

Hope the explanation is clear, and sorry for bad explanation

Comment: Thanks @Illya. :) Just one more question. What if I have to do the same kind of replacement for `orange`, `banana` and many other fruits. Do I write a separate `preg_replace` for each one of them?

Comment: no you can add the search terms using `|` separator, eg. `(apples?|oranges?|bananas?)` it will search apple/orange/banana with/without `s` ending